# Bootstrap weighted data - Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I have a simple dataset with values and absolute frequencies, like the table below:

```
value|freq
-----------
1    |  10  
3    |  20  
4    |  10  
3    |  10
```

And now I'd like to calculate the frequency table, like:

```
value|  %
-----------
1    |  1/5  
3    |  3/5  
4    |  1/5
```

And last step, I'd like to compute the **bootstrap CI** with matlab. I have a lot of rows in the dataset.

I've calculated the frequency table via `grpstats`command in Matlab, but I don't know how I can use it in the `boostrp` function in matlab.

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Bootstrap Confidence Interval of what?

Comment: Bootstrapping works on a sample, not on summary statistics. If you have the original data the frequencies are based on, then use those. Otherwise you could generate an artificial "sample" in which the values occur exactly with these frequencies. Note that the sample size matters, it has to be really 10 1s and 30 3s, etc.